# Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm trying to test my Android game in a emulator Nexus_5_API_23.  It generates an error right away.  'Unfortunately My_App has stopped...'

I'm not sure where the problem is because it's fine when I choose to run the app as a desktop application.  THis only occures when I try to run as Android

Here's the logcat:

```
03-05 09:55:34.215    1209-1209/com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.android, PID: 1209
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.android/com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.android.AndroidLauncher}: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
```

Comment: I should mention the emulator settings was NOT using Host GPU.  I will change to use it and post what happens

Comment: The software emulation was still GLES 1.x last I checked, so using the host GPU is necessary for GLES 2.